# SQLAlchemy query to find grandchildren filtered by parent and grandparent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a flask app which has projects, articles and tags.

Abridged models.py is:

```py
project_articles = Table('project_articles',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('project_id', Integer, ForeignKey('project.id')),
    Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    )

article_tags = Table('article_tags',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    )

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    articles = relationship('Article', secondary=project_articles, backref='project', lazy='dynamic')
    tags = association_proxy('articles', 'tags')

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    projects = relationship('Project', secondary=project_articles, backref='article')
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=article_tags, backref='article')
    date_created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now, nullable=False)

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    articles = relationship('Article', secondary=article_tags, backref='tag')
    text = Column(String)
```

I frequently do queries which return all the articles associated with a project which were created within a certain date range:

```py
q = db.session.query(Article)
q = q.join(Article.project)
q = q.filter(Project.id == id)
q = q.filter(Article.date_created.between(now-timedelta(hours=1), now))
articles = q.all()
```

I would also like to find all the tags associated with the above subset of articles, but I need to know how many times each tag appeared (the same tag might be associated with more than one article). I currently use python:

```py
tags = [tag for article in articles for tag in article.tags]
```

But this is slow and I am sure this is an sqlalchemy query that will do this.

Note I can do this:

```py
q = db.session.query(Tag)
q = q.join(Tag.article)
q = q.join(Article.project)
q = q.filter(Project.id == 2)
q = q.filter(Article.date_created.between(now-timedelta(hours=1), now))
tags = q.all()
```

But this is filtering the Tag table so just gives me a unique list, but I need to know how often each tag appears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, when you collect all the `Tags` for the articles returned from your query, there will be a separate SQL issued for each article, which might be slow.

**Option-1:** One way around it would be to eagerly load all the tags during the original query by using:

1. [`joinedload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload), in which case the origional query will pre-fetch also the Tags
2. [`subqueryload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload), in which case as soon as the first `Article.tag` attribute is accessed, just one more query will be issued which will load all tags for all Articles loaded with the original query.

In this case you can use your code, just add an option to it:

```
q = db.session.query(Article)
q = q.join(Article.project)
q = q.filter(Project.id == id)
q = q.filter(Article.date_created.between(now-timedelta(hours=1), now))
#q = q.options(joinedload(Article.tags)) # @new: load Tag immediatelly
q = q.options(subqueryload(Article.tags)) # @new: load Tag on first access (in the line where tags are collected)
articles = q.all()
```

and your tag collection code stays the same:

```
tags = [tag for article in articles for tag in article.tags]
```

**Option-2**: Another way would be to have a separate query like you are actually trying to do in your second code snippet. The reason why you do not get the duplicates in your query is because sqlalchemy is actually filtering duplicates out on the ORM level. To work-around this, you can already add a counter to the query itself:

```
q = db.session.query(Tag, func.count('*').label("cnt")) #@new: added COUNT
q = q.join(Tag.article)
q = q.join(Article.project)
q = q.filter(Project.id == project_id)
q = q.filter(Article.date_created.between(now-timedelta(hours=1), now))
q = q.group_by(Tag) #@new:
tags = q.all()
return tags # @note: the result is a list of tuples: (Tag, cnt)
```

Another trick would be to tell sqlalchemy to return just some columns (of Tag), and not ORM objects (Tag), in which case sqlalchemy will return all the rows without returning duplicates:

```
q = db.session.query(Tag.text) # @new:modified
q = q.join(Tag.article)
q = q.join(Article.project)
q = q.filter(Project.id == project_id)
q = q.filter(Article.date_created.between(now-timedelta(hours=1), now))
tags = q.all()
return tags # @note: the result is a list of tuples: (tag_name,)
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. I was aware of eager loading but didn't know how to 'access' the related objects which had been loaded - I see that in fact you access them as normal, it's just that no further / only one further query is made. Option 2 is perfect as I didn't mention but I was then using python collections Counter to get the frequency of each Tag - I had no idea SQLAlchemy could do that too.